# Qt Woocommerce API Returns Previous Order Data

Tags: qt, rest, api, woocommerce

I'm writing a Qt desktop application to support storing and retrieving order metadata for a Woocommerce store, via the woocommerce REST API. After updating the metadata value, Qt continues reporting the previous value.

A table widget is populated with the original data (see get code). The user edits the data and the put code is used to update the order in woocommerce. If the user goes to a different order and then back to the one that was previously edited, the get code brings back the previous data.

As an example, using the put code below, I am updating metadata of a specific order. In the example, the original value for "_shipment" is "38:1". I want to change it to "38:2".

Put code:

```
void MainWindow::ULShippmentItemMeta()
{
    //Put order item metadata back to woo

    //{"meta_data":[{"key":"_shipment","value":"38:2"}]}
    QByteArray qba = "{\"meta_data\":[{\"key\":\"_shipment\",\"value\":\"38:2\"}]}";

    QNetworkAccessManager *m_nam_putordermeta = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

    connect(m_nam_putordermeta, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(PostOrderItemMetaFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

    QUrl url(urlpath + "/wp-json/wc/v3/orders/853";

    QByteArray postDataSize = QByteArray::number(qba.size());
    QNetworkRequest request(url);

    request.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.setRawHeader("Content-Length", postDataSize);

    QString concatenated = api_key + ":" + api_secret;
    QByteArray data = concatenated.toLocal8Bit().toBase64();
    QString headerData = "Basic " + data;
    request.setRawHeader("Authorization", headerData.toLocal8Bit());

    m_nam_putordermeta->put(request, qba);
}

void MainWindow::PostOrderItemMetaFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    qWarning() << ("Server Replied With Code " + reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toString() +
                       reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpReasonPhraseAttribute).toString());

    reply->deleteLater();

}
```

Qt debugger says:

> "Server Replied With Code 200OK"

I can verify the put was successful, as is seen with Postman:

```
"meta_data": [
        {
            "id": 10362,
            "key": "_shipment",
            "value": "38:2"
        }
    ]
```

However, when using the get code to pull the value after updating, it continues to show the previous value.

Get Code:

```
    void MainWindow::on_twOrders_cellDoubleClicked()
    {
        //The order was double clicked, so lets pull it!
        QNetworkAccessManager *m_nam_singleorder = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

        connect(m_nam_singleorder, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(dlSingleOrderFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

        QUrl url(urlpath + "/wp-json/wc/v3/orders/853");
        QUrlQuery query;

        url.setQuery(query.query());

        QNetworkRequest request(url);

        QString concatenated = api_key + ":" + api_secret;
        QByteArray data = concatenated.toLocal8Bit().toBase64();
        QString headerData = "Basic " + data;
        request.setRawHeader("Authorization", headerData.toLocal8Bit());

        m_nam_singleorder->get(request);
    }

void MainWindow::dlSingleOrderFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{            
        //Gather the order data from woo, returned in JSON
        QJsonDocument d = QJsonDocument::fromJson(reply->readAll());
        qWarning() << d;
}
```

Qt debugger GET output:

```
"meta_data": [
            {
                "id": 10362,
                "key": "_shipment",
                "value": "38:1"
            }
        ]
```

I don't understand why Qt continues to show "38:1" despite Postman showing the update was successful (38:2). Appreciate any thoughts on this one.

Comment: Discovered this morning that Qt is now pulling the correct results. Perhaps some length of time is needed for a cache to clear? Still wondering though why Postman isn't affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue turned out to be related to a caching plugin owned by the hosting site. I turned off their caching plugin and now my data is coming back right away as expected.

I'm still curious as to why postman seems unaffected. That's for another day.